# AWS DMS restart process all the start point data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, dms

This may sound stupid,but i need to know few things about dms.
I am new to aws dms,I have a question about restarting and resuming the particular task.

I have a table migrating from ec2 postgres to aurora postgres.(cdc jobs)

Restart: As per the documentation(If you're using a CDC only task, you can start capturing source data changes from either the current time or from the CDC start point. If you restart the task when a CDC start point is defined, then the reload operation loads all changes from this point in time. If you restart a task without a CDC start point, then CDC changes from when the task was stopped until it was restarted are lost)

so i have a cdc task that was created 2 months ago, and it failed cause of databse patching
Note: if i restart the task will it process the data from 2 months ago or just the data coming in.

resume: The resume operation continues replicating changes from the last stop point, regardless of the CDC start point configuration.

In case if the dms is provessing all the 2 months data, what should i do to get the latest data(i.e starting point)

Any help could be appreciated.

Thank you,
Naveen